# Draw current frame during seek operations

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I'm suing `IMediaSeeking::SetPositions` to set video to some frame. But if video playback is paused, but sometimes, if I'm doing many `SetPositions` one after another are not redrawing untill I start playback again. I tried using `IVMRWindowlessControl9::RepaintVideo` after `SetPositions` but frame remained unchanged.
Is there any way to repaint current frame on pause \ during seeking in `VMR9`?

Answer (score 0):

In standard pipeline there is no entity on the filter graph to keep a last good video frame for redrawing purposes. Seeking involves flushing the remains on the line, then preloading it with fresh data from new streaming point.

If you want to provide the video renderer with a sort of a banner to be displayed while seek operation is in progress, the way I would do it is putting an extra custom filter onto video leg of the pipeline close to video renderer. The filter is to be in charge of keeping a copy of last displayed frame and it would be capable of delivering this data downstream to video renderer on seek operation before it received a valid frame from the upstream connection.

A handy copy of last displayed frame might be suitable in other scenarios as well since the filter can redeliver the data on request any time the application might need this. For instance, this can be used when VMR's mixer bitmap is updated by the application, and VMR expects next master video frame to come to visualize the bitmap update. The filter can force the update by delivering the copy of what it holds.